# Footer not sitting at bottom of container div

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I've been trying to get my footer to display properly, and have combined a number of approaches, but am still getting the same result.  The footer sits a fixed number of pixels from the top of the page, and doesn't extend all the way across the page.  I need it to display just below the content, no matter the size of the content, and for it to extend all the way across the page.

the CSS:

```
html, body, #container { height: 100%; }
#container { height: auto !important; min-height: 100%; margin-bottom:-50px;}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#4a4a4a;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'discoregular';
    left:-5%;
    bottom:0;
    top:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    body:before;
    content:"";
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding:10px;
}

#footer, #push{
    height:50px;
}

.clearboth {
clear:both;
```

}

The HTML:

```
<body><div id="container">
 <!--Content-->
 <div id="push"></div>
   </div>
 <div class="clearboth"></div>
 <div id="footer">Footer Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you reference your css file from your html, so your html should look like this, if they are in the same directory you don't need to add the path:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to/YOUR_CSS_FILENAME_HERE.css">
</head>

<body><div id="container">
 <!--Content-->
 <div id="push"></div>
   </div>
 <div class="clearboth"></div>
 <div id="footer">Footer Content</div>
```

and your css, I took away the left -5%:

```
#page {
      min-height: 100%;
      position:relative;
}

#main {
      padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#footer {
    background-color:#4a4a4a;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:'discoregular';
    display: block;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;

}
```

Comment: it is linked to the css, i just didn't include that in the HTML.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that, I edited the css so that it should resolve the formatting problem though, sorry about that!

Comment: when position is set to relative, the footer appears a fixed number of pixels from the top of the page.  when it is set to fixed, it doesnt appear at all.

Comment: How about changing the position to fixed and under #footer, #push setting background-color:#000; or some color other than white? I changed my code sample to reflect this suggestion.

Comment: now it just displays in the fixed number of pixels from the top.

Comment: Okay I think I just misunderstood, I think you want this, I just edited the code. Let me know if this works.

Comment: hmm, thats not working either.  it just moved closer to the top of the page.

Comment: is there any way i could send you my files to have you look at them?

Answer (score 0):

change the css to the following.You can chage the "bottom" so that it can come up

```
#footer {
width:100%;
display:block;
background-color:#4a4a4a;
color:#fff;
font-family:'discoregular';
left:-5%;
bottom:0;
top:100%;
height:100%;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
vertical-align: baseline;
bottom: -50px; 
padding:10px;
```

}

Comment: Thanks!  but when I change the position to 'fixed', the footer doesn't appear at all.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All I added into my footer styles after reading this post was- overflow:auto; - and it's sorted now